# Access Denied You are not authorized to access Monitoring

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have an elasticSearch cluster with 3 master and 2 data nodes. In addition, I have another node with KIbana and ElasticSearch (role=[] --coordinating-node)

The cluster is working, and I can launch the KIbana UI. However, I  see the following error when I access stack monitoring

> Access Denied
> You are not authorized to access Monitoring. To use Monitoring, you need the privileges granted by both the `kibana_admin` and `monitoring_user`  roles.
>
> If you are attempting to access a dedicated monitoring cluster, this might be because you are logged in as a user that is not configured on the monitoring cluster.

ElasticSearch 8.1
KIbana 8.1
I am logged in as the elastic superuser

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add `remote_cluster_client`role to the nodes.

Example using ECK

```
apiVersion: elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/v1
kind: Elasticsearch
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch
  namespace: elastic-system
spec:
  version: 8.1.0
  nodeSets:
  - name: default
    config:
      node.roles: ["master", "data", "ingest", "ml", "remote_cluster_client"]
```

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/modules-node.html#node-roles

Comment: should I add it to all your nodes in the cluster?
i have 3 data , 2 master and 1 coordinating node
so my roles
node.roles: [master], node.roles:  [data], node.roles: []

Comment: Thanks . I added remote_cluster_client to all my nodes in the cluster including the coordinating node but the issue still exist. Iog in to the kibana with elastic super user account

Comment: Can you try creating a new user with these roles attached? 

kibana_admin

monitoring_user

superuser

remote_monitoring_agent

remote_monitoring_collector

Comment: I have applied the above yaml using kubectl apply. It says `configured` but it is not reflecting in kibana. Do i need to restart or reload the pod? will it affect the data?

Answer (score 2):

This is how I fixed this

add `monitoring.ui.ccs.enabled: false` in your kibana.yaml

from the Doc here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/8.0/monitoring-settings-kb.html

> **monitoring.ui.ccs.enabled**
> Set to true (default) to enable cross-cluster search of your monitoring data. >The remote_cluster_client role must exist on each node.

so if you don't have remote_cluster_client role on every node, this needs to be false.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by adding new role (remote_cluster_client) in es cluster node.

Example:

```
node.roles: [ master , data , remote_cluster_client ]
```

Comment: did you add it to all your nodes in the cluster?
i have 3 data , 2 master and 1 coordinating node
so my roles
node.roles: [master], node.roles:  [data], node.roles: []

Comment: Thanks, I added it all the nodes in the cluster but same issue